# Azure Virtual Gateway gets "Not connected" when peering a vnet

Tags: azure, peering

0

I have an Azure Virtual Gateway connection from 10.29.64.128/26 to another Local Gateway that works fine.

I need some additional address space in order to outbound connections and I decide to pair another Vnet to the existing one.

As soon as I add a Vnet paired network for example to 10.29.64.0/26 to the previous one Virtual Gateway connection changes from "Connected" to "Not Connected".

Both address spaces do not overlap. What could be the cause?